# Python curses, threading: Output thread reports a lagging value for global variable

Tags: python, multithreading, python-curses

I started with a python program with curses, then I implemented threads, one which takes the input (here, the A and D buttons) and changes x accordingly. Then the main block continuously displays the value of x onto the screen. However, the values for x (a global, shared variable) are different. In particular, the value of x as measured by the main block always lags that of inputThread, but inputThread is perfectly responsive. What gives? How do I make the main block read the true value of x as measured by inputThread?

```
import time
import curses
import threading
from curses import wrapper
from time import sleep

def inputThread(stdscr):
    global x
    x = 0
    while True:
        c = stdscr.getch()
        curses.flushinp()
        if c == ord('a'):
            x -= 1
        elif c == ord('d'):
            x += 1
        stdscr.addstr("inputThread:" + str(x) + "\n" + "c:" + str(c))

def main(stdscr):
    curses.initscr()
    stdscr.clear()

    t = threading.Thread(target=inputThread, args=(stdscr,))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

    while True:

        stdscr.clear()
        stdscr.addstr("\ndisplay window:" + str(x) + "\n")
        time.sleep(0.05)

wrapper(main)
```

[image]

sample output; on next keypress, whether A or D, display window will report 9.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your global variable `x` should be declared outside all the functions but you have declared it inside the `inputThread` function. `global x` tells that instead of creating another variable within the function scope, it will use and alter the values of the global variable `x`. Hence delcare and initialize `x` with `0` outside the other functions.

Now comes your question. Suppose while the daemon and the main threads are running together, the daemon method just stuck at `c = stdscr.getch()` waiting for a key press while the `while` loop inside your main function in the main thread is doing nothing but only updating the sceen with the text `display window: 0` which you can't see because the screen gets clear in `0.05s` that the FPS is too fast to see the screen.
Now when you type either of those `a or d` keys, the daemon updates the value of the global variable `x` but before the main thread get that value, it is being printing on the virtual screen as `InputThread:*` and `c:***` and the main thread prints only the previous value `0` in this case. So the workaround is to sleep the daemon thread for a while after updating `x` as in the meanwhile the loop inside the main thread will lead to display the newly updated value of `x`. This can be done in the following way:

```
import time
import curses
import threading
from curses import wrapper
from time import sleep

x = 0

def inputThread(stdscr):
    global x
    while True:
        c = stdscr.getch()
        curses.flushinp()
        if c == ord('a'):
            x -= 1
        elif c == ord('d'):
            x += 1
        sleep(0.05)
        stdscr.addstr("inputThread:" + str(x) + "\n" + "c:" + str(c))

def main(stdscr):
    curses.initscr()
    stdscr.clear()

    t = threading.Thread(name ='daemon', target=inputThread, args=(stdscr,))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

    while True:
        stdscr.clear()
        stdscr.addstr("\ndisplay window:" + str(x) + "\n")
        sleep(0.05)

wrapper(main)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't really understand why this works, but it does. Could you explain again what's going on with this?

Comment: @FarazMasroor The last para explains it all together. If this answers your question, please accept this answer.

Comment: I can see you explained it but I don't really understand why what you said works. If the input thread updates x, then on the next cycle of the main loop the main would see the new value of x? So why does the input loop need to wait at all?

Comment: Think of the daemon thread and the main thread's synchronization

Comment: Have you ever thought of the possibility that`display window:*` would be printed at the bottom?